# Why Does SQL Server Not Return 0 for Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select 
    (case 
        when try_convert(decimal(3, 1), DEC10assessmentData.writ_literatureReview) is not null 
           then cast(DEC10assessmentData.writ_literatureReview as decimal(3, 1)) 
           else 0 
     end / 100 * 4
     + case 
          when try_convert(decimal(3, 1), DEC10assessmentData.writ_exposition) is not null 
             then cast(DEC10assessmentData.writ_exposition as decimal(3, 1)) 
             else 0 
       end / 100 * 8
     + case 
          when try_convert(decimal(3, 1), DEC10assessmentData.writ_groupReport) is not null 
            then cast(DEC10assessmentData.writ_groupReport as decimal(3, 1)) 
            else 0 
       end / 100 * 8
     + case 
          when try_convert(decimal(3, 1), DEC10assessmentData.writ_synthSummary) is not null 
            then cast(DEC10assessmentData.writ_synthSummary as decimal(3, 1)) 
            else 0 
       end / 100 * 8
     + case 
          when try_convert(decimal(3, 1), DEC10assessmentData.writ_critEvaluation) is not null 
             then cast(DEC10assessmentData.writ_critEvaluation as decimal(3, 1))  
             else 0 
       end / 100 * 12) / 40 * 100
from 
    DEC10assessmentData
```

Why does it return `0.800000000` when all values in the selected columns are `NULL`?

It returns correct results when columns have scores.

Comment: because you are divide by 100 and multiply 4 or 8  all the time, whether value is null or not

Comment: @NazirUllah But 0 returned by case statement, whether it is divided or not, should be 0 when multiplied by something.

Comment: comment all case except one then start uncommenting one by one to check where is the actual problem.

Comment: You should use ISNULL() rather than the CASE statement if all you're doing is checking for null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried creating demo here but I am getting `0.0000`, not `0.8000`. Are you sure that all values are `null`?

<kbd>**[`Null Demo`](http://rextester.com/live/ZYPBO73868)**</kbd>

If yes, the try running each case statement alone and see from which you are are not getting `0` in output.

So first run

```
select 
(case when try_convert(decimal(3,1), DEC10assessmentData.writ_literatureReview) 
is not null
   then 
cast(DEC10assessmentData.writ_literatureReview as decimal(3,1)
     ) else 0 
 end / 100 * 4
 )/ 40 * 100
from DEC10assessmentData
```

If this return only `0` then add another case statement and check further.